# Get first ten records in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

In my crystal report there are lot of records in detail page.I want first 10 *(1 to 10)*records to be shown in first page then 11 to 20 records in second page.

The header and footer must be shown same in both pages.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve that, you have to go to section expert, and under tab "paging" put "New Page After 10 visible records" (check picture).
[image]

If your group header/footer don't show on each page then you have to go right click on group -> change group, and under tab options check option "Repeat group header on each page" (check picture below)

[image]

Hope it helps